# Groovy TCP client hanging

Tags: sockets, groovy, tcp

I'm usually a .net dev (don't hurt me!) so forgive any really stupid mistakes I've made here :)

I have a TCP listener written in .net which recieves xml and sends back a response. I'm trying to write a client for it in groovy so I can load test with loadUI. Here is what I have so far:

```
def s = new Socket("10.208.24.59", 9061);
s.withStreams { inStream, outStream ->
  def reader = inStream.newReader()
  def responseText = reader.readLine()
  outStream << "Hello test server"
  println "response = $responseText"
}
s.close();
```

I'm debugging in eclipse and it is hanging on the withStreams line. What I should recieve is a "Message was not XML" message, which I can get fine via telnet.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**Update**
I've just tried this instead of the withStreams closure:

```
def r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
def w = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
w.write("Hello test server 2");
w.flush();
println r.readLine();
w.flush();
w.close();
```

Its now hanging on the println r.readLine() call

**Update again**

It turns out that this was a problem with the way the remote service was closing (or more to the point - *wasn't* closing) the stream. Both .net and our mainframe were handling it correctly but the groovy script wasn't happy. I've fixed the service and the script runs happily now, worth bearing in mind for anyone else who runs up against something similar.

Comment: My guess is the server is keeping the connection open, so the buffering reader doesn't know it's good to return (and is blocking waiting for more data).  Also, shouldn't the `"Hello test server"` be before fetching the responseText?

Comment: ok, but there can be bad services or broken connections. so, in groovy, how to implement timeout read for a robust client ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**=====  Update  ====**

Hey Chris;

Try putting the socket write outside the streams processor. You can direct the output straight at the socket since Groovy *leftShifted* the socket class. Also, not directly related, but helpful for debugging, put a socket read timeout so your thread does not block endlessly.

```
def s = new Socket("10.208.24.59", 9061);
s.setSoTimeout(3000);
s << "Hello test server";
s.withStreams { inStream, outStream ->
  def reader = inStream.newReader()
  def responseText = reader.readLine()
  println "response = $responseText"
}
s.close()
```

**=====  /Update  ====**

The problem is that [newReader](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/InputStream.html#newReader%28%29) blocks waiting for output from your server. See the stack trace below. Since you never get to send your request, there's no response from the server. In a nutshell, do not issue a listen before sending a request when using a single thread. Change your code to this and it should work:

```
def s = new Socket("10.208.24.59", 9061);
s.withStreams { inStream, outStream ->
  outStream << "Hello test server"  // send request first
  def reader = inStream.newReader()
  def responseText = reader.readLine()      
  println "response = $responseText"
}
s.close();
```

The stack trace for the waiting thread looks like this:

```
Stack trace: 
java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)
sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
   - locked java.io.InputStreamReader@2119899e
java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:136)
java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:299)
   - locked java.io.InputStreamReader@2119899e
java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)
java_io_BufferedReader$readLine.call(Unknown Source)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
```

Comment: Makes sense, but is still hanging at the same point - it appears to hang on the withStreams line, before it hits anything in the closure. Thanks for the detailed response by the way!

Comment: Still getting exactly the same - it hangs on the withStreams line (or times out if I include the timeout command. I can see the request coming through in the server logs and the "Request text was not in XML format" response being sent back. Weird, we have this running from a variety of clients quite happily. Almost ready to just give up on LoadUI as the testing tool.

Comment: I had not really zoned in on the XML and LoadUI bit..... Should the sent payload be in XML so that the server can accept it and respond accordingly ? Is there a specific format the XML should be in ? I don't know anything about LoadUI. Downloading it now...

Comment: It should yes, but for now I'm happy just getting a response from the server saying the input format is incorrect. Ideally all this would be a proper webservice, but our mainframe will only communicate through a straight tcp pipe. I've tried another method and edited the question, I'm still getting it hanging though...

Comment: Also, at the moment I'm doing this in eclipse so I can use the debugger